# Insert the query result into a temp table

Tags: sql-server

Insert dynamic query result in temp table

Tried with creating temp table and inserting to it

```
DECLARE @Currentday AS int;

SET @Currentday = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(GETDATE() AS date), '-', '') AS int);

IF @Currentday BETWEEN CAST(REPLACE(CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS date), '-', '') AS int) AND CAST(REPLACE(CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 1) AS date), '-', '') AS int)
    (SELECT ASAT,
            CIF,
            SUM(ACCOUNT_BALANCE) AS ACCOUNT_BALANCE
     INTO #SKST1
     FROM [COBG-BIU].dbo.MD_CARD_ENR_FAB
     WHERE CIF IN (SELECT CIF
                   FROM [COBG-BIU].dbo.MD_CARD_ENR_FAB
                   WHERE SPENDERTYPE = 'Revolver'
                     AND ASAT IN (CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 3, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 2, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 4)
                     AND ACCOUNT_BALANCE > 0
                   GROUP BY CIF
                   HAVING COUNT(CIF) = 3)
       AND ASAT IN (CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 3, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 2, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 4)
     GROUP BY ASAT,
              CIF);
ELSE
    (SELECT ASAT,
            CIF,
            SUM(ACCOUNT_BALANCE) AS ACCOUNT_BALANCE
     INTO ##SKST1
     FROM [COBG-BIU].dbo.MD_CARD_ENR_FAB
     WHERE CIF IN (SELECT CIF
                   FROM [COBG-BIU].dbo.MD_CARD_ENR_FAB
                   WHERE SPENDERTYPE = 'Revolver'
                     AND ASAT IN (CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 3, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 2, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 1)
                     AND ACCOUNT_BALANCE > 0
                   GROUP BY CIF
                   HAVING COUNT(CIF) = 3)
       AND ASAT IN (CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 3, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 2, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 1)
     GROUP BY ASAT,
              CIF);
```

result of the query to be inserted in a temp table

Comment: What;s wrong with the attempt above? Also, there is no Dynamic SQL above; are we missing something here?

Comment: Hi Larnu, I want the result in one table.  I can insert the result in multiple tables, however I need it in one table.

Comment: The you'll need to do multiple `INSERT` statements. A DML statement can only effect 1 object.

Comment: I did not get you, can you please guide me how to achieve it

Comment: Your comment has changed and reversed the logic you were after? What is the problem with the above, you still haven't explained. What is stopping you from doing what you want to do? An error, unexpected behaviour, your manager, (the neighbour's dog)?

Comment: Query inserts the data in two temp tables #skst1 and ##skst1, if I use only one table #skst1 I am getting the error "There is already an object named '#SKST1' in the database". I would like to insert the result in one temp table not in two. Hope this explains the problem

Comment: Have you really already created the temporary table (with SQL that you are not showing) or are you creating via insert into? If the latter then this will not work, as it is trying to create the same table twice. Instead you should specifically create the table before the inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error is because it's a compile error. You cannot attempt to make the same object twice (or more) within a single batch, even if only 1 (or less) of those DDL statements would be run. For example even this produces an error, despite that neither `INTO` could ever be be run (as 1 != 2 and 2 != 3):

```
IF 1 = 2 BEGIN

    SELECT 1 AS one
    INTO #t;

END ELSE IF 2 = 3 BEGIN

    SELECT 2 AS one
    INTO #t;
END
```

You need to `CREATE` your object first and then `INSERT INTO` it:

```
DECLARE @Currentday AS int;

SET @Currentday = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(GETDATE() AS date), '-', '') AS int);

CREATE TABLE #SKST1 (ASAT int,        --Guessed data type                
                     CIF varchar(20), --Guessed data type                
                     ACCOUNT_BALANCE decimal(12, 2)); --Guessed data type                

IF @Currentday BETWEEN CAST(REPLACE(CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS date), '-', '') AS int) AND CAST(REPLACE(CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 1) AS date), '-', '') AS int)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #SKST1 (ASAT,
                        CIF,
                        ACCOUNT_BALANCE)
    SELECT ASAT,
           CIF,
           SUM(ACCOUNT_BALANCE) AS ACCOUNT_BALANCE
    FROM [COBG-BIU].dbo.MD_CARD_ENR_FAB
    WHERE CIF IN (SELECT CIF
                  FROM [COBG-BIU].dbo.MD_CARD_ENR_FAB
                  WHERE SPENDERTYPE = 'Revolver'
                    AND ASAT IN (CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 3, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 2, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 4)
                    AND ACCOUNT_BALANCE > 0
                  GROUP BY CIF
                  HAVING COUNT(CIF) = 3)
      AND ASAT IN (CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 3, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 2, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 4)
    GROUP BY ASAT,
             CIF;

END;
ELSE BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #SKST1 (ASAT,
                        CIF,
                        ACCOUNT_BALANCE)
    SELECT ASAT,
           CIF,
           SUM(ACCOUNT_BALANCE) AS ACCOUNT_BALANCE
    FROM [COBG-BIU].dbo.MD_CARD_ENR_FAB
    WHERE CIF IN (SELECT CIF
                  FROM [COBG-BIU].dbo.MD_CARD_ENR_FAB
                  WHERE SPENDERTYPE = 'Revolver'
                    AND ASAT IN (CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 3, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 2, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 1)
                    AND ACCOUNT_BALANCE > 0
                  GROUP BY CIF
                  HAVING COUNT(CIF) = 3)
      AND ASAT IN (CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 3, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 2, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS int) - 1)
    GROUP BY ASAT,
             CIF;

END;
```

*Note, I have had to guess your data types; you will need to fix those.*

Comment: Hi Larnu, it worked, thank you very much for your help.